# Does php 5.6 support prepared statement?

Tags: php, prepared-statement, php-5.6

Does php 5.6 support prepared statement ? As I'm getting this error :

> "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on resource "

Comment: @NikleshRaut check now

Comment: Seems like `$ce_conn` is not the PDO variable.

Comment: @JashandeepSingh : please go through [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) first

Comment: @JashandeepSingh `mysql_connect` is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: you are using `mysql_*` lib which 1) does not support OOP style 2) does not have prepare statement function, consider moving to `mysqli_*` API or even better `PDO` since `mysql_*` is deprecated from PHP 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PHP 5.6 supports prepared statements. Both [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) extensions have this functionality.

What you are using here is `mysql_*` API, which has been deprecated and removed. Do not use it! Switch to prepared statements.

Additionally, PHP 5.6 is not supported anymore, and you should consider upgrading as soon as possible.

A sample prepared statement using PDO could look like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4";
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select transaction_id from tbl_sales_revenue WHERE id=? limit 1');
$stmt->execute([$_POST['id']]);
$record = $stmt->fetch();
```

Or using mysqli:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select transaction_id from tbl_sales_revenue WHERE id=? limit 1');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$record = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `prepare()` method, you need to use the [PDO Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) you can find a link on how to connect to PDO.
After the switch to PDO, you can use the `prepare()` statement.